# Dispatch to GTK+'s Main Thread Synchronously

Tags: gtk, gtk3, glib

I'm working on port some of my existing software from macOS and Windows to Linux. The basics of the software is a mutlithreaded server running behind a GUI that shows stats, generates new windows on specific events, etc.

On macOS, we have `DispatchQueue.main.sync`. On Windows / C# / WPF, we have `Dispatcher.Invoke`. We specifically use these calls in circumstances where we need the calling thread to be blocked while the UI thread is being updated. Is there something similar for GTK+?

I have been using `gdk_thread_add_idle_full` for the async portions of the code where I don't need to block, but for the synchronous version, it has been a little more complex. My current solution is a simple object containing a `GMutex` / `GCond` pair. The object is "waitable" on the calling thread, and "completeable" on the UI thread. Passing this object to `gdk_thread_add_idle_full` gives me the desired effect, but I was curious if there is a more succinct option.

The server library is as-is, so there isn't room to modify that code to behave better. I'm looking for a solution on the toolkit's side. Also, the GTK+ work is all being done in C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don’t think there’s a more succinct option, and using a `GMutex`/`GCond` pair seems reasonable for synchronising your worker thread with the reply from the UI thread.

The downside of using a `GMutex`/`GCond` pair is that it means you can’t iterate a `GMainContext` on your worker thread in the meantime. If that’s not how your application is constructed, then that’s fine.

If it is, then you might instead want to take an approach where you pass a reference to the worker thread’s `GMainContext` to the UI thread in the `gdk_threads_add_idle_full()` call. Once the UI operation is complete, the code in the UI thread would call `g_idle_source_new()`/`g_source_attach()` on the worker thread’s `GMainContext` to schedule a callback to be executed in the worker thread. This callback would update state to mark the operation as complete and returned.

In this approach, `gdk_threads_add_idle_full()` and `g_idle_source_new()`/`g_source_attach()` are both essentially message passing functions from one thread to another. In your approach, the `GMutex`/`GCond` is acting as a synchronisation fence instead.

This second approach would mean your worker thread can get on with other useful work while waiting for the UI, rather than blocking. But that might not be relevant to how your application is constructed.

Comment: Thanks for filling out the second approach. My original approach will do the job for now, but that's helpful for future use. The library I'm wrapping is wildly threaded, so I can block the calling thread without issue.